# lapack undefined reference in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, lapack

i am new to lapack and need some help. I did some searches and hope this is the right place to seek for help. i tried to

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include "C:\work\library\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\lapack-3.5.0\lapacke\include\lapacke.h"
```

as you can see, i have included the lib and dll. however, when i build it, here is what i got in the console:

```
g++ "-LC:\\work\\library\\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\\lapack-3.5.0\\lapacke\\lib" "-LC:\\work\\library\\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\\..\\lapack-3.5.0\\lapacke\\lib" -o Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack.exe "src\\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack.o" -lliblapacke 
src\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack.o: In function `Z22testLAPACK_LeastSquarev':
C:\work\library\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\Debug/../src/Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack.cpp:72: undefined reference to `LAPACKE_dgels'
```

there is certainly LAPACKE_dgels declaration in lapacke.h, though.

Comment: Are you linking with the correct library though? That's where the function should be *defined* (which is different from a function being declared).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I had liblapacke library and already configured the lib search path.

Comment: You might want to check the name of the library file, if it's named something like `liblapacke.a` (or other extension) then you should only use `-llapacke` when linking with the library. The linker will add the prefix `lib` itself. So in your case the linker tries to find a library named `libliblapacke.a`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  I made some changes and the error went away. however, when compiling, i got this:
C:\work\library\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\lapack-3.5.0\lapacke\lib/liblapack.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Answer (score 0):

It may be the right time to open your `project properties` ! It starts with a right click on your project's name. Clic on `properties`. A window with your project's properties shall open.

On the left, under `c/c++ Build` click on `settings`. There you have many tabs (`Tool Settings` , `Build Steps` , `Build Artifact` , `Binary Parsers` and `Error Parsers`)

Clic on `Tool Settings`

Here starts the important thing :

- in `GCC C Compiler, Directories` do you have soemthing like `C:\work\library\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\lapack-3.5.0\lapacke\include` in the include path ? You need it to tell to g++ the path to lapacke.h but also the path to other .h of lapacke
- in `MinGW C Linker, Libraries`, do you have `lapack` and `lapacke` under `Libraries (-l)` ? You may also need to add something in `Library search path -L` to tell to the linker where liblapack.a and `liblapacke.a are.

I hope these few words will help you, though i am pretty sure that you already know this...

Bye,

Comment: it helped. however, now i got this error msg:
g++ "-LC:\\work\\library\\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\\lapack-3.5.0\\lapacke\\lib" "-LC:\\work\\library\\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\\..\\lapack-3.5.0\\lapacke\\lib" -o Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack.exe "src\\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack.o" -llapacke -llapack -lblas 



C:\work\library\Eclipse_WinGW_Lapack\lapack-3.5.0\lapacke\lib/liblapacke.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Comment: Do you use 32bits dll and WinGW-w32 or 64bits dll and WinGW-w64 ?

Comment: my pc is win7 64bits, so i guess my answer would be 64bits together with MinGW